# How do I hide two or more directories in smb.conf?

Tags: samba

I configured `smb.conf` that works well for sharing a directory, say "samba directory", to my Windows 10 machine. Now I want to hide two sub-directories, e.g. `subdir1` and `subdir2` under "samba directory", so i added the following line in in `smb.conf`:

```
veto files = subdir1, subdir2
```

But it does not work and only `subdir2` was hidden from Windows 10 machine.

When I changed it to `veto files = subdir1`, `subdir1` was hidden well from windows 10 visiting. So, how to hide two directories from my Windows 10 machine? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

> "veto files = subdir1, subdir2"

Wrong syntax. Try:

```
veto files = /subdir1/subdir2
```

From the man pages:

> veto files (S)
>
> ```
>        This is a list of files and directories that are neither visible
>        nor accessible. Each entry in the list must be separated by a '/',
>        which allows spaces to be included in the entry.
> ```